# Convergence in LB-spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, limits-and-convergence, limits-and-colimits

**Edit:**

Let $X$ be a strict [LB-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LB-space) described by $\lim X_n$ and suppose that $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in $X$.  I'm looking for a reference showing that $x_n$ must converge in some $X_N$.

Comment: The lc case is taken care of by the fact that this is a strict $LF$ inductive limit in the sense of Dieudonné and Schwartz. The top case follows immediately.

Comment: But what do convergence sequences look like in the $LF$ space setting?  I'm only familiar with the universal property of the construction but I've never seen a discussion on convergence in that topology.

Comment: It is a great difference if you ask for convergence of sequences or convergence of nets in locally convex inductive limits: If all $X_n$ are closed (I think user131781 just forgot this assumption) then a sequence in $Y$ converges if and only if the sequence is contained in some $X_n$ and converges there. For nets nothing like this is true.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I updated the question to reflect a reference to precisely this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result (even for LF-spaces) is due to J. Dieudonné and L. Schwartz
*La dualité dans les espaces (F) et (LF)*, Annales de l’institut Fourier, tome 1 (1949), p. 61-101, propositions 2 and 4.

(Proposition 2 says that the inductive limit topology induces on the ,,steps'' their original topologies, and proposition 4 says that bounded subsets of the inductive Limit are contained in steps.)

Comment: I gave this some thought and I wonder, this means that eventually the sequence is stuck on one of the steps and not that it must always lie on the same step.  No?

Comment: If you mean by *eventually stuck on one of the steps* that there is a step which contains all but finitely many terms of the sequence then there is another step containing all terms of the sequence.

Comment: But why do we need Prop. 4?  Isn't the fact that $f \in X_n$, the fact that $X_n$ is closed, and Prop. 2 enough?